# Array - PHP - implementing values

Tags: php, arrays, api

I wrote a function that retruns this array data.. (Symfony)

```
"data": [
    {
        "1": "2"
    },
    {
        "1": "10"
    },
    {
        "1": "4"
    }
],
```

and I defined this values in an api call..

```
private function getData()
{
    return [
        'labels' => ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed'],
        'data' => [0, 0, 0]
    ];
}
```

I need to implement labels to show with returned values like so..

```
    [
        {
            "Mon": "2"
        },
        {
            "Tue": "10"
        },
        {
            "Wed": "4"
        }
    ],
```

I suppose I need to use fetch or foreach but I am stuck. I would be grateful if someone gave me instructions on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array_combine

```
$days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue'];
$arr = ['2', '10', '4'];
$combineArray = array_combine($days, $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example :

```
$days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue'];
$newArray = [];

foreach ($data as $i => $value) {
  $day = $days[$i];
  $newArray[$day] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'labels' is keys, and the values are in the array.
Use array_combine to combine the two.

```
$getdata = getData();
$new = array_combine($getdata['labels'], $dataArray);
```